# How to add visual controls to a Console application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

I am looking for a way to add visual controls into a console application. Is this supported by Visual Studio? If yes how to do it? any samples or links?

By visual controls I mean text boxes, menus, etc... Something similar to the following picture:

[image: Console application]

Thank you!

Comment: You can either find a library or roll your own. But really, why bother? Just make a regular GUI app.

Comment: Strange requirements simply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like NCurses or MonoCurses as there's nothing really built in to do this for you, interacting with the console is pretty basic.

See these links:

http://mono-project.com/MonoCurses

http://sourceforge.net/projects/curses-sharp/